# Implementing lazy initialisation in C

Tags: c, lazy-initialization

In C++, I can implement lazy initialisation with `static`:

```
struct foo { ... };
foo create_foo();
const foo& get_foo() {
    static foo x = create_foo();
    return x;
}
```

Here, initialisation occurs the first time `get_foo` is called (lazy), `get_foo` is guaranteed to be thread safe, and initialisation is guaranteed to only occur once. Specifically:

> [stmt.dcl] "Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage duration ... is performed the first time control passes through its declaration ... if control enters the declaration concurrently ... the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization"

How can I get the same behaviour in standard C?

Comment: Are you sure? I would expect that all static objects are initialized _before_ `main()` is called. What does the standard say? -- The common solution is to use a pointer initialized to `nullptr` (`NULL` in C) and then to act accordingly.

Comment: [stmt.dcl] "Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage duration ... is performed the first time control passes through its declaration ... if control enters the declaration concurrently ... the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization"

Comment: @konsolas, it's probably best to edit your question with that quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, there are no references, and you have to type `struct`, and you have to take care of initialization.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
struct foo { int a; };
struct foo create_foo();
const struct foo* get_foo() {
    static bool initialized = false;
    static struct foo x;
    if (!initialized) {
        initialized = true;
        x = create_foo();
    }
    return &x;
}
```

To be thread-safe, you can use `call_once`. Sadly, with a global variable.

```
#include <threads.h>
struct foo { int a; };
struct foo create_foo();

static struct foo global_x;
static void init_global_x(void) {
    global_x = create_foo();
}
const struct foo* get_foo() {
    static once_flag global_x_initialized = ONCE_FLAG_INIT;
    call_once(&global_x_initialized , init_global_x);
    return &global_x;
}
```

Comment: Clang says “error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant” (after `...` is filled in and `static foo` is corrected to `static struct foo`). This also would not handle the concurrency issue.

Comment: So let's do a flag!